# Display products every hour with mysql?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have issues for display the product every hour? It means, every hour the products change randomly. The only condition is after refreshing the page the order of product shouldn't change and just after 1 hour it should be change. I used mysql so I need the new method for "ORDER BY RAND(); that solve my problem or any new idea. 
here is my code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products where status = 1 ".$where." ORDER BY RAND ()";
```

how can I set time or any other function for fix it? any idea???
Even I use javascript for fixed it but id doesn't work?

Comment: Your question is unclear and I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Please rephrase your question so it's clearer ans post the structure of the products table.

Comment: I edit my question did you get my point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to change it randomly every hour would be to pass the current hour as a seed value to the `rand` function, however that will not gurantee that there will be a new product each hour - the same product could be selected again. If that's OK for your site, this is how I'd implement the random function:

```
rand(round(to_seconds(now()) / 3600))
```

To break it down:

`now()` returns the current timestamp

`to_seconds()` converts the timestamp to an int, specified in seconds since year 0.

Then we divide the value returned from `to_seconds()` by a number of seconds, for example `3600` for one hour or `60` for one minute.

This value will still change every second since it's a float with decimals. To avoid that, we have to round it to an integer.

Comment: Sorry, posted it before you rewrote your question. I thought you just wanted a random value that changed every hour.

Comment: So I should add this line after the ORDER BY()?like :   $sql = "SELECT * FROM products where status = 1 ".$where." ORDER BY RAND ( )";

Comment: Wait, re-read your qutestion again.. It might actually answer the question :D  `SELECT * FROM products where status = 1 ".$where." ORDER BY rand(round(to_seconds(now()) / 3600))` if it works the way I think

Comment: Thanks.Could you please tell me how I change the digits for 1 minutes just for testing??

Comment: Change 3600 to the ammount of seconds you want, for example 60 for one minute

Comment: yes its works thanks. I have another issue for pop-up the footer with jquery here is my code:

Comment: Post it as a new question, I'm not here to help you with your site but to help build a wiki of good questions and answers that multiple people will find useful.

Comment: No idea, as I said, ask it as a new question. And if the answer works for you, please click the accept button right next to the answer.